# How to limit messages a bot can send to 1 user

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a small bit of code, it's supposed to get all guilds the bot is in, and send 1 dm to the discord guild owner. But if the owner owns 2 servers with the bot in it the bot will send 2 messages. My question is how do I limit it to only sending 1 message to the owner?(https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/573277474721366036/575445224751366145/unknown.png)

```
        client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
            client.users.get(guild.ownerID).send('test');
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to have an array containing the users already messaged, and only send those not in the array a message. For instance...

```js
const done = [];

client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    if (!done.includes(guild.ownerID)) {
        client.users.get(guild.ownerID).send('test')
            .catch(err => console.error(err));

        done.push(guild.ownerID);
    }
});
```